# What is the name for a weed-eater head with metal or plastic blades?

Tags: weeds, tools, terminology

I am looking for a weed-eater head that does not have any plastic thread spool or ongoing feeder. It should have metal or sturdy plastic blades that don't wear away quickly?  I am (a) sick of having to deal with spooling problems and fixing the feed and (b) not keen on having tiny bits of plastic building up all over my yard.

If there is such a thing what is it called?

Comment: They're generally referred to as powerheads in my area.

Answer (score 5):

Your trimmer may or may not support them, so you may need a new trimmer. I picked my last one on the basis that it would support them...

Stihl (I'm just a customer) calls theirs:

- A "polycut head" (plastic blades)
- Two different "metal blade"
- Brush Knife
- Circular saw blade, scratcher tooth
- Circular saw blade, chisel tooth

The first three fit in in the "grass/weeds" job classification - the others get into brush/trees.

Walmart (and perhaps others) sell a thing called a "grass gator" which they claim "fits most straight shaft trimmers."

Realize that if one of these things contacts you, it's going to be rather more serious than getting whacked with string, and if one sheds a blade, it may become a hazardous projectile. The steel variety also add the possibility of sparks from hitting rocks potentially causing a grass fire.

As for search terms, I found the walmart thing (and many others) with "string trimmer metal blade" - and "string trimmer plastic blade" also gets results.

http://www.stihlusa.com/WebContent/CMSFileLibrary/downloads/Cutting-Heads-and-Blades-Selection-Chart.pdf

Answer (score 4):

I believe the google term you're looking for is "weed trimmer blades".  That will show a variety of the blades and hubs they go onto.

Of course the blades -do- wear out, but they aren't as constant a nuisance like the string.

Don't overlook a big advantage to string: if you rack the trimmer up on something hard, it only costs you a few inches of string.

Answer (score 3):

I think it goes by the following names (possibly among others)

- Brush Saw
- Clearing
- Saw Brushcutters